# GmailApp fetching email

Tags: javascript, scripting, google-apps-script

I'm trying to fetch some reports that I have on me Gmail account, everything looks fine except when I try to use a regular expression.

Te goal is to take information from the report, and paste it into a spreadsheet, but making some test I saw that sometimes, it doesn't retrieve anything from gmail(if I paste the email body on the spreadsheet I see two or three and a blank, twenty email, blank again), so I get NULL as a result of the regex.

Could anyone explain me what I'm Doing wrong? This is my first week with Google App scripting engine.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code.

```
function recopilarInformes() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search('label:informes');

  var messages;
  var ContentEmail;
  var reportDate,CFree,FFree;


  for (var i = 0; i < 20 /*threads.length*/; i++) {
    messages = threads[i].getMessages()
    reportDate = messages[0].getSubject().replace("Informe ","");
    ContentEmail = messages[0].getBody();

    CFree = /(\d+.\d+)\s.*GB/g(ContentEmail);
    FFree = /F<.td><td\s\w+\W+\w+.\w+.>\s(\d+.\d+)/(ContentEmail);

    Logger.log(reportDate);
    Logger.log(/(\d+.\d+)\s.*GB/g(ContentEmail));

  }
```

EDIT

I Came to the conclusion, despite I don't know how to exactly use the gmail objects from google app script, that regex is not the best way to acomplys my goal.

Here is the current code

```
    function recopilarInformes() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search('label:informes');
      Logger.log(threads);
      Logger.log(threads[0].getMessages());
      Logger.log(threads[0].getMessages().length);
      var messages;// = threads[0].getMessages();
      var ContentEmail;// = messages[0].getBody();
      var reportDate,CFree,FFree;


      for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
        messages = threads[i].getMessages()
        reportDate = messages[0].getSubject().replace("Informe ","");//creo si hubiera más mensajes en la conversación (thread) habría más entradas en este array, que ahora mismso solo contiene una cosa
        ContentEmail = messages[0].getBody();

        Logger.log(reportDate);
       // Logger.log(/(\d+.\d+)\s.*GB/g(ContentEmail));
        actualData = ContentEmail.split("------------ Espacio en las unidades -----------")[1];
        actualData = actualData.replace(/([^ 0-9,])/g,"").trim().replace(/\s+/g," ").split(" ");
        insertValue([reportDate,actualData[0],actualData[1]]);
      }



    }
```

Comment: I changed your app engine tag in a apps script tag.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure which one was correct.

Comment: It is not clear to me whether you are having an issue with the regex or the GmailApp. You are logging two lines here, the date and the content. Do both of these lines get skipped every 20 emails? or does only the content line get skipped ?

Comment: I Came to the conclusion, despite I don't know how to exactly use the gmail objects from google app script, that regex is not the best way to acomplys my goal.

Comment: In the new code that I posted the null is not appearing, but before, the date logs every time, and the result of expression just in pair ones.

Answer (score 0):

Use the for in loop.

```
function recopilarInformes() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search('label:informes');
  var message, reportDate;

  for (var i in threads) {
    message = threads[i].getMessages();
    reportDate = message[0].getSubject();

    Logger.log(reportDate);
  }
}
```